# How to vectorize this pandas function?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization

I need help to vectorize this function.
This is a function using the vadersentiment analysis library, to determine the sentiment of tweets in a dataset.

Any help is much appreciated.

```
analyzer = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()
def sentiment_analysis(text):
    return analyzer.polarity_scores(str(text))["compound"]
df["sentiment_polarity"] = df.apply(lambda row: sentiment_analysis(row.text), axis=1)
```

this is the `df.info()` output:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 279962 entries, 0 to 279961
Data columns (total 13 columns):
user_name           279952 non-null object
user_location       219297 non-null object
user_description    264045 non-null object
user_created        279950 non-null object
user_followers      279943 non-null float64
user_friends        279943 non-null object
user_favourites     279943 non-null object
user_verified       279943 non-null object
date                279941 non-null object
text                279943 non-null object
hashtags            218317 non-null object
source              277538 non-null object
is_retweet          279929 non-null object
dtypes: float64(1), object(12)
memory usage: 27.8+ MB
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you already have the best you can do except if you use multiprocessing (or Dask)

Comment: It takes around 31 seconds currently, but if you think its optimized then alright.